# TSql Complex Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this...

```
LEVEL        Action         Date             User
--------------------------------------------------
1            Approve        01/01/2013       User1
2            Approve        02/01/2013       User2
3            Rejected       03/01/2013       User3
1            Approve        04/01/2013       User1
2            Approve        05/01/2013       User2
3            Approve        06/01/2013       User3
.                .              .              .
.                .              .              .
.                .              .              .
```

And I want this...

Is this possible using PIVOT?

```
LEVEL1 - User 1           LEVEL2 - User 2                  LEVEL3 - User 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2013 - Approve      02/01/2013 - Approve             03/01/2013 - Rejected
04/01/2013 - Approve      05/01/2013 - Approve             06/01/2013 - Approve
         .                        .                                .
         .                        .                                .
```

**Note : Number of Level are dynamic. e.g. It can be 5 levels, 6 level etc to fully approve one item. So the number of columns in Pivoted table is dynamic.**

Comment: For dynamic number of columns - you will have to use dynamic SQL. Plenty of examples for that both on this site and across the intertnet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, I would first suggest looking at a hard-coded version of the query so you can see how the query is written before moving to a dynamic version of the query.

A static version will be similar to the following:

```
select [Level1 - User1], [Level2 - User2], [Level3 - User3]
from
(
  select 'Level'+cast(level as varchar(1)) + ' - '+ [user] col, 
    convert(varchar(10), date, 101) +' - '+ action value,
    row_number() over(partition by level order by [user], date) rn
  from yt
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([Level1 - User1], [Level2 - User2], [Level3 - User3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13881/10). You will notice that the `level` and `user` columns are concatenated to create the new columns, and the `date` and `action` are concatenated to create the value for each column.  I also added a `row_number()` to create a unique value for each row, this will be important when you apply the aggregate function in the PIVOT. If you do not use this, then you will get only one row as a result.

Since you now have a working version, this can be converted to a dynamic version easily:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Level'+cast(level as varchar(1)) + ' - '+ [user]) 
                    from yt
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select ''Level''+cast(level as varchar(1)) + '' - ''+ [user] col, 
                  convert(varchar(10), date, 101) +'' - ''+ action value,
                  row_number() over(partition by level order by [user], date) rn
                from yt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13881/11). The result for both is:

```
|       LEVEL1 - USER1 |       LEVEL2 - USER2 |        LEVEL3 - USER3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 01/01/2013 - Approve | 02/01/2013 - Approve | 03/01/2013 - Rejected |
| 04/01/2013 - Approve | 05/01/2013 - Approve |  06/01/2013 - Approve |
```

Comment: you are too good to solve pivot problems(I have seen many of your Pivots answer.).so i was thinking if you could you suggest me a good article for studying Pivot (From where you study).

Comment: Beautiful. Let me try this solution. :)

Comment: Ah! bluefeet, you saved my life. This is really wonderful. I was struggling since morning to solve this. Thanks a lot mate.. :)

Comment: @bluefeet you really mind blowing I always visit your profile. because you always answered all pivot.. really I like all your answers and your comment are also helping all new stack members..